# JButton event not working

Tags: java, user-interface, jbutton, actionlistener

My problem here is that my submit button isn't working. I'm new to working with Java GUI, and I'm not sure what I've done wrong. The textfield and button are displaying, but nothing seems to be happening with the action listener. Thanks for any help here!

```
private static void removeFlower(ArrayList<Plant> flowerPack) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("HelloWorldSwing");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    JTextField removeFlower = new JTextField("Enter name of plant to remove");
    frame.getContentPane().add(removeFlower);
    JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");
    frame.getContentPane().add(submit);
    submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String removeChoice = removeFlower.getText();


    for(Plant p : flowerPack) {
        if(p.plantName.contains(removeChoice)) {
            flowerPack.remove(p);
            System.out.println("Plant removed");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("No plant found");
        }

    }
        }});
    frame.pack();
     frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

Comment: Please define and elaborate on "isn't working" as that tells us little.

Comment: Also place a breakpoint/add a log message right in the start of action performed to make sure, the event is fired..

Comment: Sorry about that. When I enter text and click my submit button, it doesn't display either of the if-else possibilities. The interface just stays open, basically like I haven't clicked the button at all. What I am wanting it to do is after I enter the name of the flower to remove, and click submit it would display in the console if it was removed or not.

Comment: Looks like `flowerPack` is empty ! Put some .debug message as very first line in the actionPerformed()

Comment: The code works if I just add it to a main method, so maybe your flowerPack array is just empty? But why don't you just do as rob said and use a debugger or at least add a sysout in your handler. Then you'd know exactly if it's called or not.

Comment: I added a breakpoint on the actionperformed line, and it did not reach it. So it looks like the event is not being called?

Comment: Better move the breakpoint to the line where removeChoice is declared. Also, check if your flowerPack is empty or not.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I'm going to look into the function where I am adding to the flowerpack

Comment: I understand the way you are doing this thing but why not just stick to the usual way of implementing the `ActionListener` class. Especially as shown by [the java documentation from oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)